# Posting huge string through ajax to spring controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring

I'm having some trouble with posting my string to controller.

In my javascript file, I have:

```
$.ajax({
  url: myUrl,
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    jsonString: JSON.stringify(myObject)
  }
});
```

In my controller I have POST mapping:

```
@PostMapping(value = myUrl)
public void saveString(@RequestParam String jsonString) throws IOException {
...
}
```

Depending on my string size, code sometimes works, sometimes I get exception that parameter jsonString is missing.

Comment: I think the size of the string is not your problem. Once I pass in a string an image converted to base64. Must be something else...

Comment: I tried some random testing with different objects that I stringify. Max string length that I tried and is working is 1.283.075. And with 1.663.522 it fails.

Comment: Is your server set up to handle uploads that big?

Comment: Are you using Tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can add the following properties in your *application.properties*.

```
multipart.max-file-size=10Mb
multipart.max-request-size=10Mb
```

This will increase the size of the request that Spring will handle. With Tomcat, you would need to change the `maxPostSize` param present in server.xml to increase the size of Http POST request.

Another way to do it, if you are using Tomcat is to add the following code in a configuration file.

```
@Bean
EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() throws Exception {
    return (ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) -> {
        if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
            tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(
                (connector) -> {
                    connector.setMaxPostSize(10000000); // 10 MB
                }
            );
        }
    };
}
```

The default post payload size that Tomcat can receive is less than 1.5 MB, which makes sense with your example. You were able to post 1.2 MB, but with 1.6 MB it failed. So upgrading this limit, should do the trick.